# Using joyGetPosEx fails when switching joystick USB port

Tags: c++, joystick, reconnect

I am using the "joyGetPosEx" function to detect the joystick inputs:

```
JOYINFOEX joyInfoEx;
ZeroMemory(&joyInfoEx, sizeof(joyInfoEx));
joyInfoEx.dwSize = sizeof(joyInfoEx);
// poll for values
joyGetPosEx(JOYSTICKID1, &joyInfoEx);
```

When the joystick is connected, every thing is working fine and the function returns "JOYERR_NOERROR".

However, if during the program run, i disconnect the joystick and connect it to a different USB port,
the "joyGetPosEx(JOYSTICKID1, &joyInfoEx);" keeps returning a "JOYERR_UNPLUGGED" value.

If i reconnect the device to the initial USB port, it srtarts working again.

Does any one know how to make the joystick work even if it gets connected to a new port?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but FYI, `JOYINFOEX joyInfoEx; ZeroMemory(&joyInfoEx, sizeof(joyInfoEx)); joyInfoEx.dwSize = sizeof(joyInfoEx);` can be expressed more succinctly as `JOYINFOEX joyInfoEx = { sizeof(JOYINFOEX) };`. You're writing C++, not C... ;-]

Comment: Thanks, good point, but still doesn't help me :)

Comment: Hard to see how this is a real problem.  Contact the driver manufacturer for support.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have a USB device with no serial number, so Windows identifies it by where it's plugged in.  Does it start acting as `JOYSTICKID2` by any chance?

---

We eventually discovered that the `joyConfigChanged` function is able to reconnect the joystick.  [MSDN says that `#include <dinput.h>` is necessary to use this function, as it turns out, the order of includes is important: `mmsystem.h` first, then `dinput.h`.

Comment: That was my first thought, so I polled for all of the possible devices (from JOYSTICKID1 to JOYSTICKID1+15). JOYSTICKID1 keeps returning JOYERR_UNPLUGGED, and the rest simply return JOYERR_PARMS. 
That also happens if i connect a different type of joystick, it still isn't recognized. Only when the original joystick is reconnected to the original port, it starts acting correctly again.

Comment: Any joy with [`joyConfigChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757104.aspx)?  (yes, bad pun)

Comment: For some reason, i can't call the `joyConfigChanged` function.
I am including the `MMSystem.h` and linking to `winmm.lib` but when i try to call the `joyConfigChanged` function i get:
"error C3861: 'joyConfigChanged': identifier not found"

When I look at the `MMSystem.h` file, indeed the function is not defined.

Any thought?

Comment: I am including `dinput.h`. 
These are my includes:

`#define DIRECTINPUT_VERSION 0x0800

#include <dinput.h>

#include <MMSystem.h>`

However, if i add `#define _INC_MMSYSTEM` which is needed for the `joyConfigChanged` definition, then my code doesn't compile.

Comment: @Costya: Perhaps you must include `mmsystem.h` before `dinput.h`?

Comment: @ Ben Voigt

Ok, this worked. As I suspected, and as you said, ineed a call to the `joyConfigChanged` function is needed. I guess it resets everything and enables the joystick to be polled from a new USB port.

I was lacking one more include, `#include <WTypes.h>` to be exact, and that makes everything compile and work as it should. This is what my final include looks like:

`#define DIRECTINPUT_VERSION 0x0800`

`#include <WTypes.h>`

`#include <MMSystem.h>`

`#include <dinput.h>`

Thanks, your comments were more then helpful!!!

Comment: You're welcome.  I'll update the answer with this new information.